# How do I beat the Super Meat Boy arcade game?

Tags: retro-city-rampage

How do I clear level 1-7 of the *Super Meat Boy* arcade game in *Retro City Rampage*? I can get to the point where I have collected all the bandages, but I just keep running till I get killed. Do I just need to keep going to a pre-determined point or do I actually have to do something to defeat the helicopter?